# What to do when you post a partially wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

On this [coin-identification](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/39013/15625) question, I managed to find the origin of the coin correctly but I couldn't find the correct coin or the text.

An hour later, another user posted the [correct and precise answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/39015/15625).

I proceeded with adding a note on top of my answer, linking the correct answer and acknowledging my mistake.

Now the question is what should I do with my own answer?

The selfish part in me says that hey you did the work to identify the coin so you should leave it there. The principled part says that since the aim of SE is to compile correct and helpful answers, that makes my answer redundant and therefore fit to be removed. What's a man to do in these circumstances?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is something that can, or should, have a fixed rule about what to do. It all depends on the circumstances; when the answers are posted, how much new answers are guided by the existing answer(s) and how much 'better' any new answer is.

It would be trickier if your answer had been accepted (or more heavily upvoted) but, in this case, I'd suggest leaving your answer in place (as it isn't actually wrong) and upvoting the (more) correct one. You keep the rep you earned by heading in the right direction and the 'correct' answer gets the recognition.